# Connect to Mongodb replica set from another docker container failed

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker

For the purpose of using mongo transaction, I created a standalone replica set in docker:

Here are the dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo:4.4-bionic
RUN echo "rs.initiate({'_id':'rs0','members':[{'_id':0,'host':'mongodb-host:27017'}]});" > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/replica-init.js
RUN cat /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/replica-init.js
CMD [ "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0"]
```

and command line (I did not use docker-compose):

```
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --restart=always -e TZ=Asia/Shanghai --network mongo-network --name mongodb-host mongodb-image mongod --replSet rs0 --port 27017 --bind_ip_all
```

It works fine when I connect from standalone java application (with spring boot data), for URI like this:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/db_mongo?replicaSet=rs0
```

But after I built my application and deployed in docker, I cannot connect to it anymore, for URI like:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongodb-host:27017/db_mongo?replicaSet=rs0
```

I can ping mongodb-host inside this container, the network seems fine.

and BTW, it works fine before I switch to replica set.

Any ideas? Is this an authentication related issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is for k8s, but it sounds like a similar situation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62483462/2282634

Comment: Thanks Joe, but I guess I set the host as "mongodb-host" in members should match this solution?

Comment: The client machine needs to be able to resolve the hostname as it is listed in the replica set config document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to resolve this problem.

After read mongodb docker logs carefully, I noticed there was an error while rs.initiate() executing. It's weird this error only happens when I use "mongodb-host" as host name, maybe because the docker network is not ready at that point.

So I wrote a shell for init:

```
sleep 5
mongo --eval "rs.initiate({'_id':'rs0','members':[{'_id':0,'host':'mongodb-host:27017'}]})"
```

and run it seperately after docker container started:

```
docker exec mongodb-host /bin/sh /root/mongodb_rs_init.sh
```

Then it works.